# PHP replace &amp; > & not working

Tags: php, email, replace

I'm having some trouble decoding `&amp;` to `&` within a mail function:

This is the code:

```
$betreff = $_REQUEST["Betreff"];
$betreffUTF8 = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($betreff)."?=";     
$betreffFinal = str_replace('$amp;', '&', $betreffUTF8);
```

I'm pretty sure it should work like that, but for some reason it doesn't.

Any idea?

**Update:** 
Yes, the $amp; was just a typo.

Comment: Is `$` (in `str_replace('$amp`...) a typo in transcribing here?  Or is it the problem you are looking for in the code?

Comment: Your code has a very obvious typo but I think answers would be more constructive if you explained what exact problem it's trying to fix.

Comment: In which case does `base64_encode`  return an ampersand/`&amp;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find any `&amp;` inside a `base64_encode()`ed string :)

```
$betreff = $_REQUEST["Betreff"];
$betreffClean = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $betreff);
$betreffUTF8 = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($betreffClean)."?=";
```

I've reversed the operation by first replacing the `&amp` and then applying `base64_encode()`.

Comment: @Andreas - Still, I can't see why `&amp;` is the only HTML entity that needs decoding. Make sure you aren't just corrupting your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

It's `&amp;`, not `$amp;`.

```
$betreffFinal = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $betreffUTF8);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$amp;
```

don't you mean

```
&amp;
```

?